# Extracting values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a case like below:

```
  col1
  {hjjlhllllh
  :59:kjkjkjdd
  :50:/kjhjhjhsa:ddd
  :70:jnjjh


  kjkjytdvdjjh:fhghghghg
 :52:jkjkt
 :50K:kkcknkknn
 :72:nbnbds



  mvmmbmnnm{hghghgsl
 :65A:jjhjhjh
 :50B:iut6565vdjbj
```

:kjkjkj

I want it like below:

```
  col1                                                            col2

 {hjjlhllllh
  :59:kjkjkjdd
  :50:/kjhjhjhsa:ddd
  :70:jnjjh 
                                                               /kjhjhjhsa


 kjkjytdvdjjh:fhghghghg
 :52:jkjkt
 :50K:kkcknkknn
 :72:nbnbds 
                                                               kkcknkknn

 mvmmbmnnm{hghghgsl
:65A:jjhjhjh
:50B:iut6565vdjbj:kjkjkj                                     iut6565vdjbj
```

Now, I am able to get col 2 value for the 1st row by using a logic that whatever appears between '50' & ':', extract it. The Same logic does not stand correct for the other 2 rows where in I have to get that appears between '50K' or '50B' & ':'. I want to extract irrespective whatever be the prefix be for '50' without hardcoding. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of identifying a good regular expression to parse the strings into their component parts. I made an assumption that this data is sitting in a DataFrame and you are trying to add a new column with the extracted string.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def extract_second_group(full_string):
    pattern = '^\S*:50.*:\W*(\w*):\S*$'

    match = re.search(pattern, full_string)
    if match is not None:
        return match.groups(0)[0]
    else:
        return None


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'])

df['col1'] = [
            '{kjkjkjdd:50:/kjhjhjhsa:ddd', 
              'kjkjytdvdjjh:50K:kkcknkknn:nbnbds', 
              'mvmmbmnnm{:50B:iut6565vdjbj:kjkjkj',
              'not a matching string'
]

df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda col1:extract_second_group(col1))
df
```

**Explanation**

The regex pattern is `^\S*:50.*:\W*(\w*):\S*$`. Let's break it down to see what it is doing.

**^**   : Start of string
**\S**  : Matches any character which is not a whitespace character
**:50** : Match this exact set of characters (in that sequence)
**.**  : matches any character except a newline 
**\W** : Matches any character which is not a word character (matches the (/) character, if any)
**(\w*)**: This is the most important part of the expression. The \w* matches Unicode word characters, while the parentheses tell us to create a group. We are interested in capturing this group
**:**   : Another colon separates the group from the rest
**\S***  : Another non-whitespace sequence of characters
**$**   : End of string

The regex is enclosed in a function so that we can check when a regex search doesn't return a match. Call the *apply()* function to run each row through the function and return the matched group.

### Edit Jul 24 2019

This edit is to reflect the change in the data from OP.
The problem remains a question about regular expressions. Here's the code for the updated dataset

**Updated Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html
def extract_second_group(full_string):
    pattern = '\W*:50\w{0,1}:(/*[\w]*):\S*$'

    match = re.search(pattern, full_string)
    if match is not None:
        return match.groups(0)[0]
    else:
        return None



df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'])

df['col1'] = [
            '{hjjlhllllh:59:kjkjkjdd:50:/kjhjhjhsa:ddd:70:jnjjh', 
              'kjkjytdvdjjh:fhghghghg:52:jkjkt:50K:kkcknkknn:72:nbnbds', 
              'mvmmbmnnm{hghghgsl:65A:jjhjhjh:50B:iut6565vdjbj:kjkjkj',
              'not a matching string'
]


df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda col1:extract_second_group(col1))
df
```

#### Output

$$\begin{array}{c|c|}
  & col1 & col2\\
\hline 
0& \{hjjlhllllh:59:kjkjkjdd:50:/kjhjhjhsa:ddd:70:j... & /kjhjhjhsa\\ 
\hline 
1& kjkjytdvdjjh:fhghghghg:52:jkjkt:50K:kkcknkknn:... & kkcknkknn\\ 
\hline 
2& mvmmbmnnm\{hghghgsl:65A:jjhjhjh:50B:iut6565vdjb... & iut6565vdjbj\\ 
\hline 
3& not a matching string & None\\ 
\end{array}$$

**Updated Regex**
The updated pattern is `\W*:50\w{0,1}:(/*[\w]*):\S*$`.
I updated it as follows

1. **\W*** Start with some non-word characters
2. **:50\w{0,1}** Followed by :50 and 0 or 1 Unicode word characters
3. **:**  Followed by a colon
4. **(/*[\w]*)** Followed by the group we want. I included one or more / and any number of Unicode word characters.
5. **:**  Followed by a colon
6. **\S*$** Followed by any number of non-space characters to end of string

If there are other patterns you need to match, you can use the resources from https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html to locate the different options available in regex patterns.

Comment: HI, I am getting the result as none. My actual data is little different from this one. My actual data is as updated.

Comment: I think the issue is that for each row, for every filed, the data is in the new line.so may be the expression needs to chnge